# Scapulas position in freestyle/front crawl

Tags: swimming, crawl

[here](http://users.rowan.edu/%7Emantic78/muscle.anaylis.paper.pdf) a general analysis if muscles involved in freestyle/front crawl is shown.

On page 9, it is written that:

> When the arm that is close to the body similar to its position in the
> fundamental position, it first adducts and retracts the scapula, and
> then begins upward rotation in order to correctly perform the stroke.
> The muscles used in the adduction phase are the trapezius middle
> fibers, trapezius lower fibers, and rhomboids.

I am curious to know which is the scapula position (or how does it change) throughout the movement, both in the vertical plane (elevated, depressed or neutral scapulas) and in the sagittal plane (retracted, protracted or neutral scapulas).

If I have understood it correctly, at about this position the right scapula is retracted
[image]

Then what happens? Is it protracted? When? And what about elevation/depression (performed by the upper traps)?